# Rails Dynamic Highcharts Stack Bar Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, chartkick

It is possible to have dynamic name for each bar ?

Currently i have something like below. The name are same for each bar.
[image: stacked bar chart]

If you can see i want to have range of age bar chart. In 13-18 group i want to have names/tooltips 13, 14, 15, 16 but in 19-23 bar i want to have names/tooltips 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 and so on. It is possible to create something like this?

Below are my current codes to iterate data.

```html
 @i = 0
    @data = []
    while @i < 12
      @data << {
        name: @i,
          data: [["1-12", Contact.where(contact_group_id: @database.id).where.not("data ->> :key iLIKE :value", key: "phone", value: "#{@i}").size],
                       ["13-18", 16],
                       ["19-23", 28],
                       ["24-28", 16],
                       ["29-35", 28],
                       ["36-42", 16],
                       ["43-50", 28],
                       [">50", 28]]}
      @i += 1
    end
```

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what do you want to achieve? If you want to customize the tooltip you can use `tooltip.formatter`. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5jdymk1u/, API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: @WojciechChmiel i mean i want to have on different series name/tooltips for each group. If you see for group 1-12 i want to have series name from 1, 2, 3...12 but on group 13-18 i want to have series name from 13, 14, 15,16,17, and 18. It is possible?

Comment: Each point can have a name property. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tbnq5gc7/, API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.name.